# jQuery Descendant Selector Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a jQuery selector:

```
$('#myId span')
```

Is that really a performance dog vs:

```
$('#myId').find('span')
```

The first is obviously a bit cleaner to write and I'd like to stick with that if possible.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/descend-from-id-vs-select-and-find

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even know that site existed!

Comment: God, Chrome JS engine is so f*cking fast!

Comment: @Kai - Post that as an answer so that it can be accepted

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Just did + brief explanation

Comment: @Kai - thanks for posting; I'm pleased I could accept, what a perfect answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test: http://jsperf.com/descend-from-id-vs-select-and-find/3

`$('#myId span')` will cause jQuery to parse the string using its [Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle) selector engine, reading it from right-to-left, beginning its search with `span`.

`$('#myId').find('span')` will cause jQuery to select #myId immediately (bypassing the step to parse with Sizzle), and then traverse down the DOM, multiple levels, to find all descendants.

So the latter is faster.

You could also try `$('#myId').children('span')`, which might be even faster in some cases, since it will only descend a single level to find children only (as opposed to find, which keeps going).

Comment: +10 if I could - I just went back and edited a previous post and comment! Thanks so much!

Comment: I have edited the original jsPerf because I found a typo in the HTML markup. Instead of `<div id="#myId">` it should be `<div id="myId">`. Otherwise, no elements would be returned. The edited jsPerf is on: http://jsperf.com/descend-from-id-vs-select-and-find/3 Despite of the typo, as expected, `$('#myId').find('span')`is faster.

Comment: @JMPerez Much appreciated, I never noticed.

Comment: +1 for this investigation. Never thought Sizzle parses expression right2left. Sizzle developers obviously has a reason for it, but for me it stays unclear.